# Newly downloaded Texmaker Error

Tags: texmaker

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Joyous Trials No dulling

\end{document}
```

downloaded the tex maker after configuring. tested it and it gave me 3 errors . what did i do wrong?

Comment: it would help if you would mention the errors you get.

Comment: also texmaker is just an editor, have you installed latex (a miktex or texlive distribution)?

Comment: Yes i downloaded Miktek before downloading texmaker

Comment: don't use texify to compile. Compile only with pdflatex.

Comment: Truth is i am new to this, just using it for my research and needed it to merge large bibtex files. Did i miss anything in the configuration? as it seems like i missed something while watching and reading the installation process. Getting it right here will give me confidence that my files will be properly merged

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) 1. [How to make a Screenshot](https://screenshot.help/), 2. Do not make screenshots of code or error messages, instead copy them, 3. [Mark your code as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192).

Comment: you didn't miss anything. your simple document don't contain citations but texify nevertheless calls bibtex (which it shouldn't do) and that then reports errors. It is a texify problem, your document is fine.

Comment: Maybe off-topic: You want to take a screenshot of the relevant part of your computer screen (when needed), not photograph it with a camera device.